# Filling a between lines using table and line

Tags: graphics

```
Graphics[{
  Table [Line[{{0, step}, {1, step}}], {step, 0, 10}],
  Table [Line[{{0, step}, {10, 5}}], {step, 0, 10}]
  }]
```

I am trying to fill between all the lines that shown below.
Basically I just want to show it as if the right side were a light source that is turned on and as it gets farther away, the beam gets weaker/lighter.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question - feel free to correct me. Here is a solution to the question as I interpreted it:

```
rays = Graphics[{
   Table[Line[{{0, step}, {1, step}}], {step, 0, 10}], 
   Table[Line[{{0, step}, {10, 5}}], {step, 0, 10}]
   }];

rp = RegionPlot[
   y < -0.5 x + 10 && y > 0.5 x,
   {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
   ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[Norm[{#, #2} - {10, 5}]/Sqrt[125]] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   BoundaryStyle -> None,
   Frame -> False
   ];

Show[rp, rays]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[Table[
  ListLinePlot[{{{0, step}, {1, step}}, {{0, step}, {10, 5}}}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, 
     ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][Norm[{(y - 5), (x - 10)}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {step, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]